# Power Pivot - Is it possible to setup a date relationship to a table with a FROM and TO date

Tags: powerbi, dax, relationship, powerquery, powerpivot

I have been searching the internet for support with this but cannot find anything that fits the bill. I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible, so if someone can please help

I have a table of employees which contains a column 'FTE' (Full Time Equivalent) with an effective date from and effective date to. The FTE changes based on the dates from and to.

I want to create a data model that allows me to work out FTE daily and aggregate using Pivot into Weekly/Monthly/Yearly FTE

If an employee is full-time, they will show as 1.0 FTE with the dates that reflect the time they were 1.0. So example, 01/04/2022 to 31/07/2022 - this will show as 1.0 and 1 row in my data. I want to be able to calculate FTE on a monthly basis by multiplying the FTE by the number of days in the month, so potentially 31 FTE days

I'm struggling to understand how to create a relationship between the employee table with the FROM and TO dates on my date table.

A workaround that would work but is too inefficient is to create a full list of dates for each employee in PowerQuery first as this will generate 2+ million records

[image: Link to current data model]

Comment: Listen to Patrick explaining [role-playing dimensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BxaUXlx3K4).

Comment: Thanks Peter, unfortunately I don't think this gives me what I need as it will just give me data on the FROM and To dates. But I need to be able to report on each of the days in between these.

Comment: "workaround" your mentioned isn't really a workaround, it's the correct solution. Your are trying to do analysis at the daily level; therefore, your data must be at the daily level. And don't worry about 2 million records - it's a small table, Power BI is designed to handle billions of records.